# drag & drop attachement RT field

Tags: xpages

In an xpage I have a view with links to pdf files stored in RT fields in the form of :
servername/directory/nsf filename/O/id/file/docname

The user has to open the pdf file and save it locally before he can "put" it in an email. Would be nicer if the user could drag and drop the file(s) to an email directly from the Xpage.
Now when a user tries to drag and drop ,he will drag and drop the link , not the document itself. Since the database isn't available for public , this can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=drag-and-drop-attachment-links-from-file-download-control-to-operating-system-to-download

Seems to be working in Chrome only.

Comment: Thanks for this link , but most of our users have IE, so this won't work for them.

Comment: Please, let me know if you find solution for IE, it is definitely nice to have in an app.

Comment: The solution for IE is called ChromeFrame. It is not a question of code, but what the browser can do. And IE10 can.